# Flipping the last bit in a byte

Tags: python, byte, bit, xor

The ultimate objective is to flip the last bit of byte at position X. Let's say we start off with a string from a website and we base64 decode it so it's something we can work with:

```
IV = "2RDs+xm/AxtYj+XViJmBPQ=="
IV = base64.b64decode(IV)
```

That gives us something that looks like (����X��Ո��=) which looks like garbage but it's something we can work with. The best way to work with this would be to put it in a list.

```
woop = list(IV)
```

Let's say in this example that we're looking to flip the last bit at the 2nd byte. Python starts counting from zero so we need to reduce our counter by 1. Otherwise, we'll be pointing our program at the 3rd byte! To flip anything you XOR it by 1. Now here's my problem...

```
CounterX = CounterX - 1
woop[CounterX] = chr(ord(IV[CounterX]) ^ 1)
woop = "".join(woop)
IV = woop
```

I'm pretty sure that flips the entire byte. How can I tell it to flip only the last bit of the byte at IV[CounterX]?

Comment: why do you think that flips the entire byte?

Comment: No, `^ 1` would only flip the least significant bit of a byte. If the value was 255 before, it'll now be 254.

Comment: @MartijnPieters lol well there goes my answer ... and in a comment :P

`print bin(0xff ^ 0x01)`

Comment: My current understanding is that once you use base64 decode you're looking at the bytes, not the bits.

Comment: @OneManRiot: and the OP is flipping one bit in the 3rd byte.

Comment: "To flip anything you XOR it by 1" -- that's where you're wrong. To flip the least significant bit of anything you XOR it with 1. To "flip anything" might mean "to flip all the bits", in which case you do that by XORing it with -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `base64.decode` returns a string
- strings in python2x are always bytes!

  - if you are using python3 you may want to call `bytes(IV)` to ensure 8 bit chunks ... but Im not sure I dont use python3 much
- some_int XOR 1 will only flip the lowest byte

  - as demonstrated by `print bin(0xff ^ 0x01)`

so again we return to what makes you think that this is not the behavior you are seeing? can you give us an example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: This is Python 2; I've helped the OP before.

Comment: do you know if it would work the same in py3? I suspect it would(gut feeling?) ... but dont feel comfortable leaving that statement without a caveat about python 3 :P

Comment: In Python 3 you'd use a bytearray here, giving you integers and removing the need for `ord()` and `chr()` calls. `IV[2] ^= 1` is a lot easier.

Comment: Yes, this is Python 2. So are you saying that my code is correctly flipping the last bit within the byte I am targeting?

Comment: I am indeed saying that this code `woop[CounterX] = chr(ord(IV[CounterX]) ^ 1)` is absolutely flipping the last bit of whatever byte that counterX is pointing to.  again `print bin(ord(IV[CounterX])),">>",bin(ord(IV[CounterX])^1)` will easily demonstrate this fact for you

Comment: I ran that bit of demonstration code and I can now see it for myself. Big thanks! :D